# Dynamically Building a JQuery Navigation Menu from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I want to dynamically populate the values of the this menu 
(http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/sliding_menu/sliding_menu.html)
from a MySQL table. i.e. when the user clicks on the top menu botton, the menu items should be rows from the table in MySQL. I have been trying to figure it out myself for a few days but having no luck. Here is what I have done:

MySQL table: 'Countries' with these fields: id, name, capital_city
PhP File: MySQL Connection, Query and its printing out in the php file ok.
Html page with the JQuery Menu above.

If I could find an example of something similar I could probably get it to work but not finding any so far.

Anybody know of any?

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: What exactly does not work for you? You got the rows from you DB right? So where are you stuck? If you are using ajax you are getting the entries on JS-Side... and then you can append it with any HTML code you want - it is not the slightest bit clear, what kind of problem you have, since what you want to do is not that complicated. So just tell us what kind of knowlegde you need :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a PHP foreach loop on the result set you get back from the database.

```
<div id="button">
    <img class="menu_class" width="184" height="32" border="0" src="images/button.png">
    <ul class="the_menu" style="display: block;">
        <?php
        foreach ($aCountries as $aCountry) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$aCountry['name'].'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow this steps.

1) html

```
<div id="button">
   <img width="184" border="0" height="32" class="menu_class" src="images/button.png">
</div>
```

2) Onlick of button call ajaxfile that returns result of your country list like this

```
<ul class="the_menu">
  <li><a href="#">Country #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Country #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Country #3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

3) Append it to div button

this is done  now